# How to display the model only when there is one?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

How can I display the model if there is a model and display nothing when there is no model? The same behavior should be applied for all the models in the loop.

My code in **show.html.erb** is as follows:

```
<% [@car.image.url, @car.image2.url, @car.image3.url, @car.image4.url].each do |image| %>
    <%= link_to "javascript:void(0)", data: { image: image, zoom_image: image } do %>
      <%= image_tag image, id: "f1", style: '',width: "150",height: "150" %>
    <% end %>
```

How can I do something like the below code in this case?

```
<% if @car.image4.url %>
    <%= @car.image4.url %>
<% end %>
```

Expected behavior is that if we have `image4` then it shows and if not we don't to display it.

Comment: I have reworded the title, contents to fix grammar issues and explain your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

This soulds like you should be using a `has_many` relation instead:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
end

class CarsController
  # ...
  def show
    @car = Car.includes(:images).find(params[:id])
  end
end

# /app/views/cars/show.html.erb
<% @car.images.map(&:url).each do |image| %>
  <%= link_to "javascript:void(0)", data: { image: image, zoom_image: image } do %>
      <%= image_tag image, id: "f1", style: '',width: "150",height: "150" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```